# Will there be a browser version of Blender?

Tags: performance

I heard about WebAssembly, which lets C/C++ programmers target the web, I was just wondering whether Blender has any plans to make a "web" version, that runs in the browser? At the recent Google I/O, they showed AutoCAD running inside a browser using WebAssembly, so...logically, Blender should follow suit...?

After searching, I see that B is written in C and Python, and from some searching, I don't see that WebAssembly can do Python yet - maybe someone should get in touch with them?

And just to say - I have no idea WHY I want a web Blender, it just.....seems cool! :) Other projects in this area have already started - check www.tinkercad.com !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculation about upcoming features

Comment: "*so...logically, Blender should follow suit*" That doesn't seem very logical to me; there are no known plans, as far as I can tell. Honestly feel it is a waste of time, there are far more important and useful things to keep the few developers busy for a long time. That being said Blender is Open Source, nothing stops an interested third party from porting it.

Comment: Godot [recently](https://godotengine.org/article/godot-editor-running-web-browser) ported their engine to the browser, and as justification they had 2 relevant points: (1) "It will lower the barrier for new users, which will be able to try out the engine without the need to download anything." and (2) "It will allow to use Godot in a reasonable way in environments where installing/downloading applications is not an option (e.g. schools’ computers and tablets), fostering the usage of the engine for educational purposes (which is something we, as an open source community, deeply believe in)."

Answer (score 1):

No. For questions about the future of blender, check the roadmap here: https://code.blender.org/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/

There are no current plans for browser integration.

Comment: Given that the [wasm-gc](https://github.com/WebAssembly/gc) proposal is moving along, and [WebGPU](https://github.com/gpuweb/gpuweb) is already hitting browsers, it seems like the next few years *may* offer some surprises in this area. Of note is [Godot's recent experimentation](https://godotengine.org/article/godot-editor-running-web-browser) with a browser port. At the very least I'd expect an attempt at an unofficial port some time after wasm-gc lands.